# Caliber RM SDK custom tabs in C#

Tags: c#, sdk

I'm developing an Add-In for Enterprise Architect (therefore use C#) to communicate with Caliber RM (2008). I use the included Caliber RM SDK 2008. There is a documentation of this SDK (http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/images/29983/CaliberRMSDKProgrammerGuide.pdf) which is designed to help VB and Java programmers. In the above mentioned manual (on page 16) there is a way described to obtain custom tabs and their values.

However, this seems to be impossible using C#. I need to access one specific value in a custom tab, but can't obtain this value. The following shows how far I got by now:

```
Requirement req = inputRequirement; //this is the observed Caliber RM Requirement object
Collection ats = req.AttributeValues; //needed to acces custom fields

        foreach (AttributeValue av in ats)
        {
            if (av.Attribute.Name.Equals("Wanted Custom Field"))  //The specific field I look for 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Name: " + av.Attribute.Name);
                //MessageBox.Show("Value: " + ???);
                break;
            }
        }
```

This example is running and displays the name (in this case only "Wanted Custom Field"). Analogous to the VB example on page 16 of the manual, you would assume there is a way to display the value by simply accessing

```
av.Value
```

But there is no field in

```
AttributeValue
```

for this purpose. I found some other ways to display the custom tab/field names, but none of them let's me obtain the value. The above shown code example seems to be the best try, but I'm not even completely sure about that.

My question: **is there a way to obtain the value in C#?** The "documentation" (above mentioned pdf) was no help at all for me.

EDIT: I just tried to use VB.NET to obtain the value, but it seems that there is also no value for the AttributeValue. I'm actually lost right now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution from the support which I will provide here:

```
public string GetCustomFieldValue(string custFieldName)
    {
        Collection attrValues = requirement.AttributeValues; //requirement is a Caliber RM 'Requirement'

        for (var i = 0; i < attrValues.Count; i++)
        {
            AttributeValue av = (AttributeValue) attrValues[i];
            if(av.Attribute.Name.Equals(custFieldName))
            {
                if (attrValues[i] is UDAListValue)
                {
                    UDAListValue values = (UDAListValue)attrValues[i];
                    return values.SelectedValue.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```

`custFieldName` is the custom field I was looking for and the method is returning the value of this field. If anyone ever encounters the same problem I hope this helps.